# Find and Replace Strings in a Column with Data from Another Table?

Tags: php, mysql, string, replace, find

I have:

Table_A:

> ID | **post_content**
>
> 1 | This is bla bla url1.com
>
> 2 | This is another text blah blah url2.com
>
> 3 | This is a third text blah blah url3.com
>
> 4 | There are many such article texts of wordpress blogposts with more matching strings in it
>
> 5 | ...

*Table_B:*

> StringsA  |  StringsB
>
> url1.com  |  link1.com
>
> url2.com  |  link2.com
>
> url3.com  |  link3.com
>
> ...url600 | ...link600

post_content from Table A are wordpress article texts which may contain a few strings somewhere in this text that match with the ones in StringsA.

I need to replace those strings in the post_content column with the corresponding strings from StringsB so it would look like this:

Table_A:

> ID | **post_content**
>
> 1 | This is bla bla link1.com
>
> 2 | This is another text blah blah link2.com
>
> 3 | This is a third text blah blah link3.com
>
> 4 | There are many such article texts of wordpress blogposts with more matching strings in it
>
> 5 | ...

What would be the easiest way to do that? Can I do using only MySQL, or should I use a PHP script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

You can do it with a query... carefully, of course.

```
update Table_A, Table_B set post_content=replace(post_content, StringsA, StringsB)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply phatfingers, but I tried with the replace function like you mentioned and only the strings from the first row of the column StringsB got replaced which were only 4 in the post_content text. Everything else stayed intact. The columns StringsA and StringsB have about 700 values, how to find and replace every single one of them?

Comment: Meh. It looks like the replace() function is doing its job, but update thinks it's done with each row after the first hit, even with every row in one table joined to every row in the other.

Comment: I think you may have to take that PHP approach.  If you loop through your list of TableB strings, you could iteratively call "UPDATE Table_A SET post_content=replace(post_content, ?, ?) WHERE post_content LIKE '%?%'" with StringsA, StringsB, StringsA as parameters.